# How to install Cuda toolkit on GitHub Codespaces

Tags: cuda, thrust, codespaces, github-codespaces

I would like to compile Cuda code, in particular code that uses the library Thrust, on a GitHub codespace (one without GPU). I do not need to be able to run the Cuda code.

I installed the NSight VS Code extension but in my understanding I also need to install the Cuda toolkit. How can I install it?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/developing-in-codespaces/getting-started-with-github-codespaces-for-machine-learning#configuring-nvidia-cuda-for-your-codespace

Answer (score -2):

CUDA is for GPUs. You won't be able to install it on a Codespace without a GPU.